# Use animation as a third axis in react chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm coming from plotly and I want to essentially do [this](https://plotly.com/python/animations/) in chart js, specifically with react.

Would I create the animation frame by having a `useEffect` and timeout change the data every time interval or is there a builtin way or existing plugin already?

Comment: No you will need to update the chart yourself.

Comment: @leelenalee thanks. Should I memo them?

Comment: I don't have that kind of knowledge of react